# How to get "new" Figure/Table labels to retain linked Heading Style in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, styles, caption

I have a Word 2016 template (for this purpose, we'll call it Template 1) in which I have defined a multi-level list for use in appendices linked to Headings 7, 8, and 9 (Appendix A, A.1, A.1.1, respectively) - Headings 1-6 are part of the same list (1.0, 1.1, 1.1.1, etc.).  I have created new labels for appendix figures and tables (such that they are numbered A-1, A-2, B-1, B-2, etc.) and set the numbering to "Include chapter number" and "Chapter starts with style" is set to Heading 7. I saved the new labels to my normal.dotm template, and they now are available to me in any Word document. However, when I open a document (with Template 1 attached), the "Chapter starts with style" for my appendix labels has reset to the default of Heading 1.

Is it possible to get the new labels to retain Heading 7 as the chapter setting? If so, how?

Comment: See http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html and http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html. It sounds like what you are attempting. Can you attach a link to a sample document?

Comment: I find a similar thread "[Heading 2 (Chapter starts with style (Heading 2)) for table caption numbering (ex, Table 1.2-1) in a little bit complicated setting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/heading-2-chapter-starts-with-style-heading-2-for/fa3d5826-6b29-4471-9287-e2dd9cfa9d57)", it seems that you need a maco.

Comment: Charles and Emily, thank you both for your replies. Unfortunately none of those offer a solution to my problem. The heading styles are fine, and I can manually change the heading style linked to the chapter number for my captions. What I need is to be able to changed the linked heading (in this case Heading 7) and have it stay that way going forward, instead of reverting back to the default settings for the caption every time I open a new document (or reopen an existing one).